# Arithmetic mean of normalized scores or a direct geometric mean?

Tags: mean, normalization, social-science, geometric-mean

My question is about studies like the following: 
[The 2015 SEDA Scores by Country](https://www.bcgperspectives.com/content/articles/public-sector-sustainability-2015-seda-scores-by-country/), PDF is available [here](https://www.bcgperspectives.com/Images/BCG-Why-Well-Being-Should-Drive-Growth-Strategies-May-2015.pdf).

The authors collect 43 indicators for 149 countries and compute a well-being index based on these numbers. Unfortunately they don't explain how they compute the index. But since the indicators comprise a wide range starting from GDP per capita, quality of roads, Gini coefficient, press freedom etc. my first idea would be to combine these indicators to an overall index using a geometric mean.

However the authors mention in the appendix, that each indicator is normalized into a scale of 0-100. Since the scale starts at zero, I believe they cannot use a geometric mean, so my guess is they use an arithmetic mean to compute the index in the end.

So my question is: In such a case should one use an arithmetic mean of normalized scores or better a geometric mean of the indicators without normalization?